# material angular chips with autocomplete

Tags: angular-material, md-autocomplete, md-chip

I have a md-chips with autocomplete, but the text in the autocomplete excedes the width and is showed like this:

[md-chips with autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e53vL.jpg)

So, the idea is the suggestbox uses a 100% width or adjust to the word size.

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.name" placeholder="Search for a vegetable">
    <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.name}} :: {{item.type}}</span>
  </md-autocomplete>
```

http://codepen.io/dvelasquez/pen/BjeoYq